# sequelizejs ( nodejs orm ) can't sync model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have this part of code
i want to sync it, but can't

```
this.sequelizeCon = new this.sequelize('mydb', 'root', '', {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 3306
})
var revision = this.sequelizeCon.define("revision",{
  version :{
    type:this.sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey:true,
    allowNull:false
  }
})

revision.sync();
```

i got this error response

```
[TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply']
```

can anyone give me known what's wrong with my code..?

Comment: Hmm besides the fact, that you don't have any callback for the syncing  (maybe that's the problem, but hopefully not :D), everything looks quite ok. Which version of sequelize are u using? Is this.sequelizeCon.sync() also not working?

Comment: i use sequelize version 1.6.0-beta4, i already tried this.sequelizeCon.sync too... and i got the same error... i tried to find what value in " [object Object] ".. but i can't print it...

Answer (score 0):

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize').Sequelize;

var dbConnector = function () {
    const DB_NAME = 'spring'
    const DB_USER = 'root'
    const DB_PASSWORD = ''

    var sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,
        {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 3306,
            dialect: 'mysql'
        }
    );
    var revision = sequelize.define("revision", {
        version: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })
    revision.sync()
};

dbConnector()
```

```
"mysql2": "^2.2.5",
"sequelize": "^6.5.0",
```